# Integrating wordpress in an existing site - the permalinks issue

Tags: wordpress, integration, permalinks

How do you use wordpress capabilities (using wp-blog-header.php) and keep the permalinks behave?

I have a pretty complicated website, so recreating it within wordpress isn't an option. However, I want to have a blog within the site. For those reasons and more limitations, I have to use wordpress capabilities OR curl call, so the wordpress content will live between my website header and footer.

I used wordpress capabilities with including the wp-blog-header.php in my site, and queries really work with a little effort BUT as you would probably expect, the permalinks link to the blog itself (which is external to my site).

How can I make it work that the permalink to a single post / a category etc. will stay at the scope of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "dont".

If you choose to use wordpress externally, you will have to create the permalink by yourself.
Usually that shouldn't be a big deal but if you want to cover all "pretty url's" scenarios it is a pain.

Finally, I used a CURL request to the Wordpress installation and injected the rendered HTML to my site. 
with some mod_rewrite I made the whole system run smooth.